# Keep getting a value error after altering my code

Tags: python, string, tkinter

So, I've been trying to run this program but whenever I press enter to start it (that part works fine) it keeps throwing this error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

And this is the line which triggers this:

```
words = ["Games","Development","Keyboard","Speed","Typer","Anything","Aplha","Zealous","Accurate","Basics","Shortcut","Purpose","Window","Counter","Fortress","Modification","Computer","Science","History","Football","Basketball","Solid","Phantom","Battlefield","Avdvanced","Warfare","Download","Upload","Antidisestablishmentarianism","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious","Discomobobulation","Liberated","Assassin","Brotherhood","Revelation","Unity","Syndicate","Victory"]

def nextWord():
        global score
        entry.focus_set()
        if entry.get().lower() == words[1].lower():
            score += 1

        entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        random.shuffle(words)
        label.config(str(words[1]), text=str(words[0]))
        scoreLabel.config(text="Score: " + str(score))
```

I am aware that it could be in the

```
(str(words[1])
```

part because I changed a bit of the code there to try and fix another error (which I did). So is there something I'm missing/missed out?
Thanks.

Comment: There's not nearly enough code here to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Full code and traceback error.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to do with `label.config(str(words[1]), text=str(words[0]))` ?

Comment: This is the only line where it's telling me there's an error?

Comment: Just posting the line that has the error isn't sufficient. We need a [mcve].

Comment: Also, I'm trying to get values from a list and display it in a label and I've added the rest of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
label.config(str(words[1]), text=str(words[0]))
```

`config` only takes one named argument, but you're giving it a named argument and a positional argument. Try:

```
label.config(text=str(words[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and next time I'll try to structure my questions properly.